# Selecting varchar with spaces at end

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with varchar(15) column Code, which is also primary key. In one of the rows, value of this column is "K553". When I do select with `WHERE Code='K553  '` this row is selected even when no spaces are in that string! Also when I try to add new row with value "K553 " I get error which says that primary key already exists. If I add some spaces to start of string, not end of string then it works as expected. What is this behavior?!

Comment: This is standard behaviour for a varchar type

Comment: If you really need codes with significant trailing whitespace, this is very unfortunate for you. But do you?

Comment: Why this behavoir? Because it makes sense!

Comment: @jarlh You insert something and select it by criteria that does not correspond to inserted data. This makes sense to you???

Comment: Hey, this sentence has a trailing space at the end . Can you read it? (Character types are more or less for human langauge. You can even have case insensitive primary keys, and get k553 returned.)

Comment: Is there any way to turn of this crap and select only data, that are corresponding with where clause? This works in Oracle database by default.